# Optical Illusion with status indicators

Tags: website-design, optical-illusion

I'm currently setting up a small html front end for the result of our automatic software build. We develop on three platforms ( windows, macos and linux ), so I thought of just displaying the icon of that platform with a background color representing the status.

Like this ( each row is preceded by additional information, like date, which I didn't include )

[image: sample]

However when viewing this from afar it seems like the central green rectangle extends further upwards.

[image: sample from afar]

How can alter this design to avoid this effect?

Comment: this is a really bad design for colorblind people. but yes red and green arent equally lumnious to people with standard vision.

Comment: Using borders is one way to solve this. Although I might suggest changing the design approach. Maybe something like the [badges commonly used on repos](https://github.com/dwyl/repo-badges) would be better, one badge for each platform.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best approach would be to separate the icons slightly:

[image: green and red with borders]

If you use a low contrast separator, such as your current background colour, then you will need quite a wide separator, but if you go for something higher contrast, such as white, then the separators can be quite narrow.

Alternatively, you could adapt the colour scheme to something tonal, rather than with such contrasting colours. Maybe something like this:

[image: alt colour sheme]

Of course, another option would be to just leave it as it is. It might look slightly odd to some people's eyes, but it serves the purpose of communicating the information that you need it to communicate.